Is there an Italian grammar that compares the language against classical Greek and Latin?
I am searching for a grammar and syntax of the Italian language (in English, French or German), composed with the approach of classical languages (Greek and Latin) grammar and syntax.
I am sure that someone used to classical grammars can precisely understand. However I could illuminate: When I say e.g. "approach of classical languages grammar", I mean a complete morphological analysis of the inflection/conjugation, quoting clearly the theme, the affixes, the phonological rules, the meaning of the morphemes etc., maybe with some historical/etymological notes about the components. Similarly and analogously about syntax.
Thanks a lot.
Addendum. If this "ideal grammar" appears in a method of learning italian with fragments from italian literature included (i.e. a literature based method), then it would be great twice.
